# Sliding form - jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple survey website where you have to answer questions 1 by 1. When you are done with a question by clicking an answer, the page will fade out and fade in to the next one.

I have been searching for a way to do this, I'd like it to save the answered questions to the database once the survey is finish.

Any ideas?

So far I have this one:

[jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/zLekb/](http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/zLekb/)

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#site").cycle({
        fx : "scrollHorz",
        next : ".next a",
        prev : ".prev a",
        startingSlide : 1,
        timeout : 0
    });
  });
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #page1, #page2, #page3, #site {height:100%;width:100%}
.prev, .next {
    display:table;        
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    width:1.5em;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
.prev{
  left:0
}
.next{
  right:0
}

.prev a, .next a {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:1.5em
}
.prev a:hover, .next a:hover {color:#eee;}
.prev a{
    border-radius:0 0.5em 0.5em 0;   
}
.next a{
    border-radius:0.5em 0 0 0.5em;
}
p {padding:2em}
h1 {font-size:2em;padding:1em;font-weight:900}
```

I just want to know if there are other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kVCb2/1/)

```
$("#brand").change( function() {
    $(".next a:visible").click();
});
```

Beware that on IE radiobuttons and checkboxes only issue a "change" event when the focus changes to the next control in the form. So for these it's better to use the "click" event.

To save it you must have a submit button at the end of the form that will either submit the form in a traditional way to a server side page or do an ajax request.

I've just updated the Fiddle to show the radio button handling.

BTW, what I am doing is sending a click to the "next a" to make it slide when a control is selected or clicked.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an event handler on the next page and save the results in a `form` with hidden inputs

Then at the end, bring up a `save button` which will `serialize the form` and send it to the server via POST.

On the server you'll have a `php` or any other server side language to read the Data from POST and save then in the database.

Comment: You need to set an event handler on the next page and save the results in a form with hidden inputs

How exactly do i do that? Sorry but I am kinda new in Javascript/jquery